# flash cc on iphone5 - margins on top and bottom

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, fullscreen, flash-cc

I'm using flash CC to create an app for iPhone5.
In flash CC I start a new air for iOS file. I get a stage of `640x960`. The stage is empty and there's no code. I publish, check it out on the iPhone and I get margins on the top and bottom. 1 cm each. It simply won't cover the whole screen.

I tick the full screen box in the settings -> still get the margins.

I add: `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;` -> still get the margings.

I change the stage's size to various `sizes -> all` the same.
What am I missing? how do I make these margins disappear?
(I just want to see my empty stage covering the whole iPhone5's screen)

Answer (score 0):

after many searches I found the answer to my problem here:
http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/07/deploying-air-apps-on-iphone-5/